# SQL query to pull a value as of ~90 days away from the value as of a different date

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is that I have a row in a table with a value, a date, and a tag of Y or N.

```
Unique ID Value             Date          Tag   
1          10         1/1/2018   Y
1           5         4/17/2018  N
```

I need to make sure that the value as ~90 days away (with the N tag) has a value half or less of the original (<=5 in this case).  There could be any number of rows in between, before, and after, and I need to get the one closest to 90 days away and make sure it is half of the value with the Y tag.  If the file closest to 90 days away IS less than half, tag it with a Y, else a N.

This is something I've never had to do before, so I'm hoping someone here can help!

P.S. sorry for the horrid formatting!

Comment: What does ~90 days away mean?

Comment: About 90 days. The value in this scenario is a count of records on a file received - the need is to check if the file received about 90 days later has 50% of the records of the original (as rows should drop during this 90 days). I say about 90 days because the files are not necessarily received in consistent increments.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date closest to 90 days away as:

```
select t.*, t2.value as about90dayvalue
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.uniqueid = t.uniqueid and
            t2.tag = 'N' and t2.date < t.date
      order by (datediff(day, t2.date, t.date) - 90) ;
```

I don't know what "make sure" means.  But this brings the two values on the same row.